# Detect Apple TV home button tap and convert into UIPress type to get AVPlayer's current time

Tags: objective-c, tvos, apple-tv

In short, I am looking for implementation of tapped method from https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/DetectingButtonPressesandGestures.html

In Detail:

I am developing tvOS app using Objective-C. When I use AVPlayer to play video, I want to record player's current time when user press home button.

```
        // Play the stream
        player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
        AVPlayerViewController *pvc = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
        pvc.player = player;

        self.player = player;
        self.playerViewController = pvc;

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
        tapGestureRec.allowedPressTypes = @[@(UIPressTypeMenu), @(UIPressTypeSelect)];
        [self.playerViewController.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRec];
```

Here, I am getting tap captured in below method but don't know how to check it's homebutton tap from remote.

-(void) tapped: (UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {

//implementation ?

}

I tried below implementation but it's crashing:

-(void) tapped: (UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {

```
    UIPress *press = (UIPress *)sender;

    if(press.type == UIPressTypeMenu) {
        // Do what you want
        // ...
        cmTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentTime), self.player.currentTime.timescale);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%ld", (long)press.type);
    }
```

}

Error:
2017-03-08 09:45:35.991 XXXXX[63556:3612942] -[UITapGestureRecognizer type]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080001bddc0
2017-03-08 09:45:35.997 XXXXX[63556:3612942] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITapGestureRecognizer type]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080001bddc0'

It's first time to use apple tv remote, so I need your help. Other post couldn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

The "Home Button", is the one labeled with a TV and it is handled by tvOS, it is not possible to use it for custom gestures.

It is even not part of the definition of UIPressType.

```
public enum UIPressType : Int {
    case UpArrow
    case DownArrow
    case LeftArrow
    case RightArrow
    case Select
    case Menu
    case PlayPause
}
```

On the other hand, your code is actually creating a gesture for Menu and Select buttons.

The crash is due to this piece of code:

```
UIPress *press = (UIPress *)sender;
if(press.type == UIPressTypeMenu) {
```

Which is casting an instance of `UIGestureRecognizer` to `UIPress` which is a completely different thing. It crashes when trying to call a method of UIPress because it is actually a different class.

If you want to perform different actions for each gesture recognizers, you should consider having 2 different gestures recognizers instead of trying to detect the actual press that triggered the action from a single.

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    UITapGestureRecognizer *menuGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(menuKeyWasPressed)];
    menuGestureRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = @[@(UIPressTypeMenu)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:menuGestureRecognizer];


    UITapGestureRecognizer *selectGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(selectKeyWasPressed)];
    selectGestureRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = @[@(UIPressTypeSelect)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:selectGestureRecognizer];
}

-(void)menuKeyWasPressed {
    NSLog(@"Menu key was pressed");
}

-(void)selectKeyWasPressed {
    NSLog(@"Select key was pressed");
}

@end
```

Comment: It helps. Thanks. I will definitely try this.